# How to $group the collection data having same user_id in mongodb using golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to make the sum of the price of the product which having same `user_id` using golang. But I don't know how I will get this. I tried `$group` in the following code

Struct for product

```
type Product struct {
  Id         int     `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
  Name       string  `json:"name" bson:"name"`
  Sku        string  `json:"sku" bson:"sku"`
  Category   string  `json:"category" bson:"category"`
  Stock      int     `json:"stock" bson:"stock"`
  Price      float64 `json:"price" bson:"price"`
  Sale_price float64 `json:"sale_price" bson:"sale_price"`
  UpdatedOn  int64   `json:"updated_on" bson:"updated_on"`
  UserId     int     `json:"user_id" bson:"user_id"`
}
```

Struct for the customer

```
type Customer struct {
  Id               int    `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
  FirstName        string `json:"first_name" bson:"first_name"`
  LastName         string `json:"last_name" bson:"last_name"`
  Email            string `json:"email" bson:"email"`
  PhoneNumber      string `json:"phone_number" bson:"phone_number"`
}
```

function from where the data will retrieve

```
func GetProducts(c *gin.Context) {
    mongoSession := config.ConnectDb()                                         //connection to database
    collection := mongoSession.DB(config.Database).C(config.ProductCollection) //session
    pipeline := []bson.M{
        bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"user_id": 1}}, bson.M{"$sum": bson.M{"price": "price"}},
    } //query i tried
    fmt.Println(pipeline)
    pipe := collection.Pipe(pipeline)
    resp := []bson.M{}
    err = pipe.All(&resp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Errored: %#v \n", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
    GetResponseList(c, response)
}
```

The data viewed in the image-

[image]

In the above image the `user_id` of the product is same. I want to group this data and calculate the `price`.

I also read the documentation of the Mongodb [this one](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) but don't understand how to do in golang can anyone explain it in simple way how to make the query for this.    Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When grouping using `$group`, you have to use the special `_id` property to tell what you want to group by.

And when referring to existing properties / fields, you have to use the `$` sign in front of their names, e.g. `$user_id`.

And besides the `_id` you may list additional properties whose value may be some aggregate value (like `$sum`).

This is how your pipeline may look like:

```
pipeline := []bson.M{
    {
        "$group": bson.M{
            "_id":       "$user_id",
            "sum_price": bson.M{"$sum": "$price"},
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Thankyou giving me this answer. it works . but can i do it with the `$match` also?? @icza

Comment: @Puneet What do you want to do with `$match`? You can include filtering with `$match` in pipeline, sure.

Comment: okay thanks i just asking because I'm reading the other documentation of the mongodb that's why

Comment: How to read _id value in go lang after group?

Comment: @ManishSharma The same way you read `_id` of any documents.